# Least squares projection coefficient

Tags: self-study, econometrics

I am dealing with a problem from the book Econometrics of Hayashi (2000) and can't really figure it out unfortunately. I was wondering if anyone perhaps could help me. The question is as follows:

> Consider the model $y_i=\textbf{x}_i'\beta+\textbf{z}_i'\delta+\epsilon_i$ with $\mathbb{E}(\textbf{x}_i\epsilon_i)=\textbf{0}$; $\mathbb{E}(\textbf{z}_i\epsilon_i)\neq\textbf{0}$ and $\mathbb{E}(\textbf{z}_i\textbf{x}'_i)=\textbf{0}$. Thus, $\textbf{z}_i$ is not predetermined, it is not orthogonal to the error term, but it is unrelated to the predetermined regressors $\textbf{x}_i$ in that the cross moments are zero.
>
> Show that the least squares projection coefficient of $\textbf{x}_i$ in the projection of $y_i$ on $\textbf{x}_i$ and $\textbf{z}_i$ is $\beta$.
>
> $\textbf{Hint:}$ calculate $\hat{\mathbb{E}}^{*}(\epsilon_i|\textbf{x}_i, \textbf{z}_i)$.

The hint is especially confusing to me.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: The use of a hat and a star over the expectation operator is unusual.  Could you explain what they mean?  Also, may we presume that "$\prime$" is a transpose and not some other kind of operation?  Finally, the use of the subscript "$i$" appears to be inconsistent, not least because it seems that $y_i$ represents a *number* (for any specific $i$), calling into question what it would mean to "project" it onto vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{z}_i$. This suggests you need to explain the notation, with particular attention to the dimensions of each object.

Comment: Let me try to clarify some things. First of all, I understand the orthogonality, but not what the use of a projection is. Also, cross moments is a term which I can´t get a grasp on. Thus far I have encountered hints which were the starting point that lead me to what I was looking for. Therefore, I think that I need to find the hint. How can you calculate it, and what are the implications fo the conditional $x_i, z_i$?

Sorry, I was not aware that this is an unusual notation. The hat and stars are to indicate that it is the least squares projection. The "$\textbf{'}$ indeed is the transpose.

Comment: Finally, I do not really understand the inconsistency. The vectors $x_i, \beta, z_i$ and $\delta$ should all be bold and are of a 'K-dimension'. The multiplication thus leads to numbers, as we multiply a row-vector by a column-vector. Hopefully this is of any use.

Answer (score 1):

I was also puzzled by this question. If anyone is interested, it is review question 4 (partitioned projection) from section 2.9 of Hayashi's book Econometrics. From page 139, in the general model $ y = \mathbf{x}^T \boldsymbol{\beta} + \epsilon $ the $\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$ that satisfies the orthogonality condition
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbf{x} \cdot \epsilon \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbf{x} \cdot \left( y - \mathbf{x}^T \boldsymbol{\beta}^* \right) \right] = \mathbf{0} \quad \text{or} \quad \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \right) \boldsymbol{\beta}^* = \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x} \cdot y \right) 
$$
$$
\implies \boldsymbol{\beta}^* = \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \right) \right]^{-1} \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x} \cdot y \right),
$$
provided that $\mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \right)$ is non-singular. The least squares projections of $y$ on $\mathbf{x}$, denoted $ \hat{\mathbb{E}}^* \left( y \, \left| \, \mathbf{x} \right. \right) $, is defined as $\mathbf{x}^T \boldsymbol{\beta}^*$, where $\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$ satisfies the orthogonality condition above.

Keeping this in mind, I think that the hint is asking you to do the following:
\begin{align*}
\hat{\mathbb{E}}^* \left( \epsilon_i \, \left| \, \mathbf{x}_i, \, \mathbf{z}_i \right. \right) &= \hat{\mathbb{E}}^* \left( y_i - \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} - \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} \, \left| \, \mathbf{x}_i, \, \mathbf{z}_i \right. \right) \\
&= \hat{\mathbb{E}}^* \left( y_i \, \left| \, \mathbf{x}_i, \, \mathbf{z}_i \right. \right) - \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} - \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_i^T, & \mathbf{z}_i^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{\beta}^* \\ \boldsymbol{\delta}^* \end{pmatrix} - \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} - \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} \\
&= \mathbf{x}_i^T \left( \boldsymbol{\beta}^* - \boldsymbol{\beta} \right) + \mathbf{z}_i^T \left( \boldsymbol{\delta}^* - \boldsymbol{\delta} \right).
\end{align*}
You could argue that it has been shown that $\boldsymbol{\beta}^* = \boldsymbol{\beta}$, however it seems a little shallow and I haven't used any of the aforementioned orthogonality conditions.

The partitioned normal equations are
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} &= \mathbf{x}_i y_i \tag{1} \label{eq:norm1} \\
\mathbf{z}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{z}_i \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} &= \mathbf{z}_i y_i \tag{2} \label{eq:norm2}
\end{align}
Resulting in the following expression for $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}} &= \left[ \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right]^{-1} \mathbf{x}_i \left( y_i - \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\hat{\delta}} \right) 
\end{align}
So, using the orthogonality condition:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\beta}^* &= \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \right]^{-1} \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i y_i \right) - \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{z}_i^T \right)}_{ = \mathbf{0}} \boldsymbol{\hat{\delta}} \right] = \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \right]^{-1} \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i y_i \right) = \mathbf{b}_{OLS}. \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\implies \boldsymbol{\beta}^* - \boldsymbol{\beta} &= \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \right]^{-1} \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i y_i \right) - \boldsymbol{\beta} \\
&= \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \right]^{-1} \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \left( \mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta} + \mathbf{z}_i^T \boldsymbol{\delta} + \epsilon_i \right) \right) - \boldsymbol{\beta} \\
&= \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \right]^{-1} \left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{x}_i^T \right) \boldsymbol{\beta} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \mathbf{z}_i^T \right)}_{=\mathbf{0}} \boldsymbol{\delta} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left( \mathbf{x}_i \epsilon_i \right)}_{=\mathbf{0}} \right] - \boldsymbol{\beta} \\
&= \boldsymbol{\beta} - \boldsymbol{\beta} = \mathbf{0}. \\
\implies \boldsymbol{\beta}^* &= \boldsymbol{\beta}.
\end{align}